# getPackageManager and MockPackageManager

Tags: java, android

I wanted to get a list of installed apps on a device **by** using `getInstalledApplications()` method from `MockPackageManager` class (Yes it is deprecated). I used the following code (in my activity):

```
MockPackageManager mpm = new MockPackageManager();
List<ApplicationInfo> appInfoList = mpm.getInstalledApplications(0);
```

But it gave me this error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/test/mock/MockPackageManager;
```

then found this way (which worked):

```
 List<ApplicationInfo> appInfoList = getPackageManager().getInstalledApplications(0);
```

I looked at Android docs but only found these:

> Class for retrieving various kinds of information related to the application packages that are currently installed on the device. You can find this class through getPackageManager(). [PackageManager docs]
>
> Return PackageManager instance to find global package information.[Context docs about getPackageManager()]

I really didn't understand **why** the first way is wrong and **why** I should first use `getPackageManager()` (**what** does it do?).

Tnx in advance.

P.S: Sorry if it is a simple(stupid!) question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described in the official documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/mock/MockPackageManager.html), `MockPackageManager` is a (deprecated) test class for mocking the package manager behaviours.

In the description there is stated:

> All methods are non-functional and throw
>   UnsupportedOperationException. Override it to provide the operations
>   that you need.

Which is usefull only if you want to test some of your code involving the package manager.

To access the real implementation you have to use the real [PackageManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getPackageManager()) class using

```
PackageManager pManager = getPackageManager(); //in a context environment
```

or

```
PackageManager pManager = context.getPackageManager(); //in a non-context environment
```

Comment: But isn't PackageManager  an abstract class?!
And again I didn't understand what getPackageManager does!
TnX

Comment: Yes `PackageManager` is an abstract class, and calling `getPackageManager()` which is a Context method as descibed [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getPackageManager()) you get a real implementation of the abstract class. PackageManager is used to get info about installed packages on the device

Comment: As I said before, I read the link you provided in your comment, but didn't understand much. But now with your explanation, I got it. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

```
    try {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, mPermission)
                != MockPackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{mPermission},
                    REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSION);

            //  If any permission above not allowed by user, this condition will
            //  execute every time, else your else part will work
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

that was my code snippet. I had an error MockPackageManager. then i changed it to PackageManager. and fixed the problem